# How to pass compile-time logging source generation code method input as serilog.Ilogger instead of Extensions.Logging?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, serilog, serilog-aspnetcore

Below is sample code for passing Microsoft.Extensions.logging as input of logging partial method.but my scenarios is how pass Serilog.Ilogger as input of logging partial method.

```
  [LoggerMessage(EventId = 0, Level = LogLevel.Information, Message = "Generating {customer}")]
    private static partial void LogCustomerCreated(
ILogger logger, [LogProperties] Customer customer);
```

Answer (score 0):

To use Serilog with Microsof.Extention.Loggin you need to use this package "Serilog.Extensions.Logging".

You then need to create the Ilogger with LoggerFactory

```
SerilogLoggerFactory loggerFactory = new SerilogLoggerFactory();

ILogger<Program> newLogger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();
DataProcessor dataProcessor = new(loggerFactory.CreateLogger<DataProcessor>());
```

Can you share more information about the part where you create the log